# SQL query to get a value from XML in one table and update a column in another table with that value

Tags: sql, xml

I have got two tables, Table A containing my subject that needs to be updated and Table B that contains XML used to populate the columns in Table A.

A new column has been added to Table A which relates to a specific piece of  in the XML.

Any ideas how I can query the XML and insert the  into the new column?

UPDATE:

I have tried to query the XML using

```
  select 
      xml
  from 
      TableB
  where 
      xml.value('(/path/value)[1]','string') like 'VALUE'
```

However when I do this, "xml.value" is highlghted as an error "***Cannot find either column "xml" or the user-defined function or aggregate "xml.value", or the name in ambiguous***"

Comment: Please provide DB type (SQL Server + version, MySQL, Redshift, etc.), sample data, and expected output

Comment: Sorry. It's SQL server. Not sure what version. As for output, ideally i need to insert the value of the select into the blank column in Table A but if I could even just display the value it would be a great help